# iOS 10 crash on deallocating_deinit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting a crash error on the view controller deinit. It happens very randomly on iOS 10.

Has anyone run into the same problem?

**Crashlytics Log**

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2e84f6 objc_msgSend + 21
1  Foundation                     0x1dad4e77 -[_NSConcreteObservation dealloc] + 96
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2f5195 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 238
3  Foundation                     0x1d99de9d empty + 32
4  Foundation                     0x1d8f8787 -[NSConcreteMapTable removeAllItems] + 76
5  UIKit                          0x22a09259 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _clearLayoutVariableObservationsOnlyToSupportTAMICChange:] + 56
6  UIKit                          0x222212f9 discardEngineRecursive + 298
7  UIKit                          0x22221279 discardEngineRecursive + 170
8  UIKit                          0x22221279 discardEngineRecursive + 170
9  UIKit                          0x22221279 discardEngineRecursive + 170
10 UIKit                          0x2211c66b -[UIView dealloc] + 798
11 UIKit                          0x221f9cdb -[UITableViewCell dealloc] + 330
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1d06a4df common_removeAllObjects + 182
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1cf89a47 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 14
14 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2f5195 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 238
15 UIKit                          0x2245eddb -[UITableView .cxx_destruct] + 1602
16 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2da047 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
17 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2e4ec5 objc_destructInstance + 34
18 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2e4ee5 object_dispose + 14
19 UIKit                          0x224aae93 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 138
20 UIKit                          0x2211c9a1 -[UIView dealloc] + 1620
21 UIKit                          0x221fa353 -[UIScrollView dealloc] + 732
22 UIKit                          0x222acda1 -[UITableView dealloc] + 484
23 UIKit                          0x22872de7 -[UIPickerTableView dealloc] + 228
24 UIKit                          0x229ce133 -[UIPickerColumnView .cxx_destruct] + 144
25 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2da047 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
26 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2e4ec5 objc_destructInstance + 34
27 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2e4ee5 object_dispose + 14
28 UIKit                          0x224aae93 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 138
29 UIKit                          0x2211c9a1 -[UIView dealloc] + 1620
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1d06a4df common_removeAllObjects + 182
31 CoreFoundation                 0x1cf89a47 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 14
32 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2f5195 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 238
33 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2da047 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
34 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2e4ec5 objc_destructInstance + 34
35 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2e4ee5 object_dispose + 14
```

Comment: Is there a line of code that Xcode points to or is this just an arbitrary crash? Also does it happen when the same action is performed more than once - is it repeatable? If so it may be an issue with the code. I've had random crashes in iOS 10.2 before, for no real reason - it was mainly due to the device I was using in the Simulator somehow, still no clue why it happened.